# How to use Search bar to search website in iOS app

Tags: xcode, ios5

A simple question to experienced programmers.  I am trying to use Search bar to link another search bar in my website. 
I hope that when user type keywords on search bar in apps,the webview will show the page.

The point is how to link the two search bar in app and website, or Appple don't allow this action.

I am very new ios developer.

ps. the search bar in my website: http://www.searchandbuy.com.tw/

Answer (score 0):

Using json(my preference) on the server side, it's possible to grab the data from your website's query by doing something like:

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.searchandbuy.com/tw/"];
NSString *args = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",/*some variable in which you store your user's input here*/]
args = [args stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@search?q=%@",baseUrl,args];
NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
//NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error; 
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [json objectForKey:@"searchResults"];
```